# How to determine the 'toggle' status of a CSS toggle input?

Tags: html, css, toggle

I would like to implement a CSS-based toggle/switch input. I found the example of the following link which is really easy and not using javascript at all. The problem is that it's lacking the explanation of how to determine the 'toggle' status

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

This is the full code for reference:

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I didn't tried the simple solution.. well it's working now :)

`document.getElementById("input").checked`

Answer (score 1):

If the html is like this

```
<label  class="switch">
    <input id="showflagsswitch" onclick="showFlags()" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
```

Then this javascript will give you the value

```
switchFlags=document.getElementById("showflagsswitch").checked;
```